# how to prevent timer to start the delay in the first time its start?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a timer that makes a certain action when it is running (interval of 1000 ms), Is there some way to prevent the timer to start the delay and in the first time instead to go into the function and start to do the code ?

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelStatus.Text = "Waiting for next file" + "(" + (class.property / 1000).ToString("#0.##0") + " seconds)";
    class.property -= 1000;
}
```

i want the timer will start immediately to count (update the label) instead of waiting 1 sec before the first label update

Comment: There are several timers in .NET, which one are you using? Show your code.

Comment: i am using Winform timer

Comment: Can you just call the method directly? The method you have for you OnTick can be just called directly.

Comment: Jeff has a good example below.

Comment: a boolean flag is note the answer? your question is not very clear IMHO..

Comment: This question is poorly phrased. Example code here might help...

Comment: i update my question, see code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What prevents you to extract the code running into the Timer_Elapsed event and create a standalone procedure (a.k.a. Refactoring).
Once you have your procedure call it just before starting the timer.

For example from this:

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, TimerElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    int a = 0;
    for(i=0; i<100;i++)
       a += i;
}
```

to ....

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, TimerElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ExecuteCalc();
}
private void ExecuteCalc()
{
    int a = 0;
    for(i=0; i<100;i++)
       a += i;
}
```

and in your code:

```
ExecuteCalc();
Timer1.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: i have files in my List box which i am running, if the next file will come with more than 3 sec delay, bool variable change to true and than from the main GUI i am checking this class all the time (with BackgroundWorker) and then with event the timer start and read the number of sec it need to count down (another variable) but my problem is that the timer linger in the function entry and than the countdown finish 1 sec before its need

Comment: i did not understand what that's doing

Answer (score 3):

Rather than going about it how you are, you can simply execute the code which your timer is supposed to when it ticks right before you enable it.

Example:

```
public Main()
{
    DoWork();
    Timer1.Enabled = true;
}


protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, args e)
{
    DoWork();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just "fake" a call to your tick handler like this:

```
timer_Tick(null, null);
```

when you first start your timer. However, this is bad form and it's better to extract your code (refactor) it into a method and call the method. Then have your handler call the same method as Steve noted:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     UpdateLabel();
}

private UpdateLabel() 
{
    labelStatus.Text = "Waiting for next file" + "(" + (class.property / 1000).ToString("#0.##0") + " seconds)";
    class.property -= 1000;
}
```

Now call it just like Jeff has shown you:

```
UpdateLabel();
timer.Enable = true;
```

Comment: i did not understand what the function UpdateLabel() doing, whats the trick ?  where put the line timer_Tick(null, null) ?

Comment: @user1269592: What do you mean you don't understand UpdateLabel()? It's your code! I copied it from your question! As for the timer_Tick line, as I said, don't do it. Refactor and call UpdateLabel (or whatever you want to call it) instead. Where's your code to start your timer in the first place? Put you call to UpdateLabel there, as I showed you in the last snippet.

Comment: i try your example but same result, i am call the timer with event, maybe this can help: http://csharptips.wordpress.com/tag/system-threading-timer/ i will glad if someone can show me in how to write it (i try with no succeed)